# What is the process for updating from one LTS to the next LTS?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, lts

I just installed Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I have been receiving and installing maintenance updates.  When a new LTS release becomes available down the road - say for example - 20.xx LTS, what is the process for updating that new LTS release? Does it happen as a regular part of my Kubuntu update that preserves my existing data and configuration? Or am I faced with a full wipe of my existing system and a re-install of everything?  I see this question has been asked and answered before, so I just want to confirm that the update process on my existing machine will offer the new LTS upgrade at the appropriate time, after the new LTS has become stable, and that I do not have to use command lines to accomplish an LTS to LTS update.  Thank you.

Comment: The next LTS won't be until 20.04.  LTSes come out once every 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

The next LTS (assuming Canonical follows the pattern of the last several years) will be 20.04, which should release approximately April of 2020.

The safest method of upgrading is: don't upgrade.  Backup all your data and do a clean install.

Even if you do upgrade (using `sudo do-release-upgrade`), you should make a complete backup of all data you want to keep before you start -- if something goes wrong, you could wind up accidentally losing everything on your storage device.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the usual GUI updater will offer to update to the new 20.04 LTS when the time comes (i.e. no command line required).

Comment: @PerlDuck once they open the upgrade track, yes.

Comment: The reason for my question: I'm seriously considering cutting the Windows cord and using Kubuntu only for all my large computer needs.  I'd like to make sure I have a stable upgrade path into the future without having to back everything up and do a full reinstall every time a new LTS comes up.

Comment: @TonyR  Same reason I started using Linx back in 2011 (then MEPIS, I switch to Kubuntu when MEPIS started getting old and wasn't updating).  With the ease of installing Ubuntu, I've found it's actually easier to put my /home in a separate partition and tell Ubuntu to reuse that partition (with a new username) each time, than to get a version upgrade to go through successfully.

Comment: @TonyR [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) applies to computers. The day you lack backups is the day you will need those backups. Ubuntu will try very hard to preserve your data (done many without any problems over a decade)...but Ubuntu does NOT guarantee it.